# Error during Generating Catalog Templates installation step Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to install Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-3 on my local machine, and the SIF installation stopped during the following step.

> Importing Module => SitecoreUtilityTasks
>   [GenerateCatalogTemplates : GenerateCatalogTemplates]
>   Generating Catalog Templates ...
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : 
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I try to open my XP instance, I see the following error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetEntityIdFromMappings(String sitecoreId) +100
>      Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID itemId, CallContext context) +177
>      Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID itemID, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +146
>      Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemInformation(ID itemID) +87
>      Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemDefinition(ID itemID) +18
>      Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.LoadItemBasedTemplate(ID templateId) +40
>      Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.AddItemBasedTemplates(TemplateDictionary result) +196
>      Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.InternalGetTemplates() +492
>      Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.GetTemplate(ID templateId) +190
>      Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.d__0.MoveNext() +170

I have no idea of what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**

Looking into XP logs, I found the following issue:

> 1428 19:04:47 ERROR Authentication Error
>   Exception: System.Exception
>   Message: The certificate thumbprint is invalid or missing from your configuration, secure communication with the Commerce Engine is not possible.
>
> ManagedPoolThread #9 19:04:47 ERROR An error occurred while loading mapping entries: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.LoadMappingEntries()
>   Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source: Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect
>   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.LoadMappingEntries()

The certificate's thumbprint in the App_config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config file looks correct.

[image]

Comment: Stack traces and error messages need to be included as real text, please. Search engines won't decode your images.

Comment: Is there anything useful in your XP logs?

Comment: Please check the associated log file and update the question, if you find something relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the help and feedback. I have updated my original post with the requested information. I am not sure what I need to do here.

Comment: @JoãoNeto I've also updated my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the exact same issue when XP couldn't connect with the commerce engine. If this is the case, you should see an error in the XP log files as Rob has indicated. Did you check these and did you check the engine connection settings in `App_config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`?

**Update:**
The thumbprint in `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config` needs to be the same as that configured in

- `CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\config.json`
- `CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\config.json`
- `CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\config.json`
- `CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\config.json`

(Under the Certificates -> Certificates element.)
Also, make sure that the configured CertificateHeaderName is the same as the one configured in `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`, in your case `X-CommerceEngineCert`.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought as well, smells a bit like an incorrect certificate thumbprint in the patch file

Comment: @jonne-kats, the thumbprint and certificate header name match in all configuration files. Looking into the CommerceAuthoring logs I saw the following error `00001 09:27:07 ERROR An error occurred while reading the key ring. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Encryption-Keys\'.` I don't have drive C: in my machine, it is named X:. Can I simply update the config files or do I need to reinstall commerce again?

Comment: @JoãoNeto Yes should be able to just modify the location in the wwwroot\config.json file. Make sure that the apppool user has permissions to write to the folder you specify.

Comment: @JonneKats which app's config.json file are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still having this issue, it could be related to sql credentials. You get the same issue in case sql policy is not correct on the commerce engine side.